# Run queries on SQL Server then switch over to Oracle to run another set of queries

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I have a set of queries that run in SQL Server on Server1. I then have another set of queries that run in Oracle on Server2. I have one master script for server1 that runs my queries for me. Then I have another script for server2 to run a different set of queries. Is it possible to make it run them all consecutively without me having to intervene to switch over to the other server? Something in the script that would go like......

Server1 Scripts
query1
query2
query3
query4
query5
some code to switch over to server2
Server2 Scripts
query1
query2
query3
query4
query5

Comment: probably based of the name of your scripts

Comment: I'm doing all of this within SQL Developer. I attempted to just have one script run it all. The script starts off in SQL Server and runs them fine but as soon as it gets to the queries that run in Oracle, the script bugs out and says it doesn't see the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Have your script start with the connect command. The connect command in the worksheet allows you to specify the entire JDBC connect string which includes the driver. So what can be done is connect to the server do work then connect to the other server and do more work.

I don't have a sqlserver hand but should be basically like this:

```
-- connect to oracle
conn klrice/klrice@orcl
@myscript1
@myscriptN
-- connect to sql server
conn klrice/klrice@"jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433/Blog"
@myotherscript1
@myotherscriptN
```